# multi robots in uwsim

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I tried to load two robots in environment, in order i put two  tag with different position for them and also different topic for their navigation, but when i send data to topic of second robot, it is disappeared! is it possible at all to handle multi robots in uwsim ( i need to have many robots) and if it is possible how?! and also it is possible spawn robots inside of code or all thing must be handeled in XML file?

Thanks in advance.

it's my scenes:

```
blah blah blah ...
<vehicle>
    <name>visual</name>
    <file>data/scenes/r2d2_mm.urdf</file>
       <jointValues>
      <joint>0 </joint>
    </jointValues>
<position>
      <x> 0.2</x>
      <y> 0 </y>
      <z> 0.0 </z>
    </position>
    <orientation>
      <r>0</r>
      <p>0</p>
      <y>0</y>
    </orientation>

  </vehicle>

<vehicle>
    <name>visual1</name>
    <file>data/scenes/r2d2_mm.urdf</file>
       <jointValues>
      <joint>0 </joint>
    </jointValues>
<position>
      <x> 3</x>
      <y> 0 </y>
      <z> 0.0 </z>
    </position>
    <orientation>
      <r>0</r>
      <p>0</p>
      <y>0</y>
    </orientation>
  </vehicle>
.
.
.
    <rosInterfaces>
        <ROSOdomToPAT>
          <topic> /dataNavigator </topic>
          <vehicleName> visual </vehicleName>
        </ROSOdomToPAT>
    
        <ROSOdomToPAT>
          <topic> /dataNavigator1 </topic>
          <vehicleName> visual1 </vehicleName>
        </ROSOdomToPAT>
  </rosInterfaces>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196899/multi-robots-in-uwsim/) by [VahidD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4674/vahidd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

It is possible to handle multiple vehicles, please have a look at shipwreck.xml scene, where two vehicles are placed in the scene and can be controlled through "/dataNavigator_G500TRIDENT" and "/dataNavigator_G500RAUVI". Not sure where is the error is in your case, your config file looks OK.

By now it is not possible to spawn vehicles, we are working on it.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2014-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1